# in views row-template, how to obtain rendered output of each item in multi-valued field?

Tags: 7, views, theming

I have a custom row template, and I know I can obtain the rendered field output with:

```
$field_output = $view->render_field($fieldname, $view->row_index);
```

For a certain multi-valued field, I would now like to create an array of the rendered output of each item in the field.

```
$field_output[3] = rendered field output for 3rd item in my multi-valued field
```

Anyone know how I can do this?

**UPDATE:**

There are two approaches I am aware of, but neither is a good, robust solution.

#### Approach #1:  get_values()

One approach is to call get_values, and then grab the safe_value:

```
$vals = $view->field[$fieldname]->get_value($row);
$field_values = array();
foreach ($vals as $i=>$v){
  $field_values[$i] = $v['safe_value'];
}
```

The problem with this approach, as described [here](http://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/rendering-drupal-7-fields-right-way), is that (a) it breaks localization and (b) some fields do not have a safe_value.

#### Approach #2: render_field()

The second approach (see below) uses render_field() and then explodes the result:

```
$field_values = array();
$field_output_str = $view->render_field($fieldname, $view->row_index);
if (!empty($field_output_str)){
  $separator = ',';
  $field_values = explode($separator, $field_output_str);
}
```

The problem with this approach is that, in addition to exploding multi-valued fields, it also explodes individual fields that contain commas, such as text fields.

Does anyone have a better, more robust solution?

Answer (score 1):

If the field is multi-valued, then $view->render_field($fieldname, $view->row_index) returns a comma-separated string of the individual rendered items:

```
rendered_item0,rendered_item1,rendered_item2,...
```

To generate the array `$field_output_array` where `$field_output_array[2] = rendered_item2`, explode the string:

```
$field_output_string = $view->render_field($fieldname, $view->row_index);
$separator = ',';
$field_output_array = explode($separator, $field_output_string);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a robust solution.   It does not work for multi-valued fields that contain commas within the field values.  For example, if I have a text field that contains 20 commas, and I use the ',' separator to explode $field_output_string, then I end up exploding that text field into 21 pieces.

Does anyone know a more robust solution, for programmatically rendering multiple-valued views-fields?